# Failed to launch Camera when parameters set on Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parameters, camera

When i set the parameters on the camera to modify different aspects of it, and then show it via a SurfaceView, it doesn't show the preview of the camera once the application is launched.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    imageViewCapturedPhoto = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageViewCapturedPhoto);
    imageViewCapturedPhoto.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    Matrix mirrorMatrix = new Matrix();
    mirrorMatrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceView.invalidate(); }
private void initCamera(int cameraWidth,int cameraHeight){

    if(isPreview == false){
        int numberOfCamerasInDevice = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        camera = Camera.open(1);
        surfaceView.invalidate();

        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            Camera.Size size = getBestPreviewSize(cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            camera.startPreview();
            isPreview = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("myApp", "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
```

If i comment the parameters set on the Try/Catch, the camera starts, but doesn't have any parameters set.

Comment: Make sure whether your device supports the size from `getBestPreviewSize()`

Answer (score 0):

```
final Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
final Size size = getOptimalSize();
params.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Instead of use getBestPreviewSize() try with getOptimalSize().